# Mysql how to find the attribute except max value and min value

Tags: mysql

the original query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE l_extendedprice > (SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice)
                         FROM LINEITEM)
      AND
      l_extendedprice < (SELECT MAX(l_extendedprice)
                         FROM LINEITEM);
```

how to make it simple?

Answer (score 0):

Another similar ways:

Using JSON:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS((SELECT JSON_ARRAY(MIN(l_extendedprice), max(l_extendedprice))
                     FROM LINEITEM), JSON_ARRAY(l_extendedprice)) = 0;
```

Using UNION:

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE l_extendedprice NOT IN (SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice)
                              FROM LINEITEM

                              UNION ALL 

                              SELECT MAX(l_extendedprice)
                              FROM LINEITEM);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice) min_price, 
       MAX(l_extendedprice) max_price
FROM LINEITEM
```

returns both the min and max `l_extendedprice`s in 1 table scan.

Join it to the table under your conditions:

```
SELECT li.*
FROM LINEITEM li 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice) min_price, 
         MAX(l_extendedprice) max_price
  FROM LINEITEM
) t ON li.l_extendedprice > t.min_price AND li.l_extendedprice < t.max_price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM cross JOIN (SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice) as minvalue ,
                                 max(l_extendedprice) as maxvalue 
                         FROM LINEITEM ) as a
WHERE l_extendedprice != a.minvalue And l_extendedprice != a.maxvalue
```

another way to avoiding use subquery

```
SELECT MIN(l_extendedprice) minvalue, 
       MAX(l_extendedprice) minvalue into @minvalue,@minvalue
FROM LINEITEM;
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM 
WHERE @minvalue != a.minvalue And  @minvalue != a.maxvalue
```